# Управление access token'ами

Tags: .net, http, архитектура, .net-core

Допустим у меня есть сервис на `.core`. Время жизни моего `access token` я задал порядка 30 минут. Какой у меня `UI` не имеет значение, может быть веб морда на каком нибудь `angular.js`/`vue.js` или вообще на `WPF`.

Для того что бы обновлять `access token`, использую так называемый `refresh token`, техника не новая.

При логине я получаю пару токенов - `access token` и `refresh token`. `Refresh token`, если так можно выразиться, принадлежит только одному единственному `access token`, всякий раз когда я запрашиваю новый access token, предоставляя `access token`, я его "убиваю" - ставлю ему флаг `revoked`.

Есть ряд вопросов :

1. Как мне правильней работать с `refresh token`? Раскрываю вопрос : когда я делаю запрос к сервису и мне приходит `401` я делаю запрос на новую пару `access token/refresh token`. При этом на клиенте у меня стоит монитор на `access token`(1 на запись и много на чтение). Это правильный подход?
2. При обновлении `access token`, я могу выбросить две ошибки - `RefreshTokenAlreadyRevoked` (данный `refresh token` уже был использован) или `RefreshTokenNotFound` (`refresh token` не был найден). И при появлении этих ошибок на клиенте (при запросе новой пары) я просто "выбиваю" юзера на логин скрин. Это правильно?
3. Необходимо ли сохранять `refresh token` в базе? Может быть у меня был перезапуск сервиса?! Но если мой `access token` живет не более 10 минут, а пользователей в системе , для примера, более 1000 и каждый имеет запрашивает новую пару `access` и `refresh token` порядка 10 раз за сутки, у меня каждый день будет копиться мусор. Но опять таки возвращаясь к пункту 2 у меня есть ошибка - `RefreshTokenAlreadyRevoked`, то есть я какое то время должен его еще хранить?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Доступ к приложению должен осуществляться только по основному токену.

`Refreshtoken` обычно предназначен для обновления основного токена по истечении его времени жизни, чтобы не хранить пароли в приложении и не вызывать форму входа каждый раз. Поэтому если основной токен уже не действителен, на сервер отправляется `refreshtoken` (если он есть) и по нему обновляется основной токен.

Соответственно у `refreshtoken` время жизни должно быть достаточно большим, а у основного токена наоборот достаточно коротким. Как вариант, можно сохранить `refreshtoken`и дату его создания в таблице БД и по истечении времени жизни подчищать не нужные токены.

Если и `refreshtoken` отсутствует или и у него истекло время жизни, тогда повторная авторизация через форму входа.

Comment: В вопросе я кажется и написал что у меня refreshtoken для обновления acesstoken

Comment: Речь не об этом. Когда Вы получаете от сервера ошибку 401 и у Вас есть действительный `refreshtoken`, нужно по нему обновлять основной токен, а не запрашивать заново оба токена. Если и `refreshtoken` уже недействителен, тогда да. От повторной полной авторизации не уйти.

Comment: я предоставляю refreshtoken и получаю по нему, если он действителен, новый refresh token и access token, старому ставлю метку что он уже использован.

Comment: а если refresh token "протух" или его нет, то полная авторизация.

Comment: Так и надо обрабатывать 401-е ошибки.

Comment: перечитайте пожалуйста вопрос внимательней